# Desktop PC's DVI-out stopped working

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, display, dvi, repair

I have a desktop PC with two video outputs — one *VGA-out* (connected to a monitor), and an extra *DVI-out*, for which I bought a DVI to HDMI cable to connect to a TV. The cable worked fine after I plugged it in, and I've had no problems with it until someone accidentally kicked it out of the TV.

The cable's short, and has to hang a bit to make it to the TV. While the cable guy was over, he stepped on it, pulling it out of the HDMI socket. Since then, **nothing the DVI-out is plugged into ever gets a signal**.

There's nothing wrong with the cable or TV — I have tried other cables and monitors. It's as if there was never a DVI-out to begin with. Not even the BIOS screens show up. I can only guess that *something* is preventing the desktop's DVI-out from carrying a signal.

The PC still works, and nothing looks bent or broken at the back, so I'm at a loss.

Any idea what might be wrong?